# If my British boyfriend visits me in the US for a month this December, how long could he stay in the summer?

Tags: visas

My boyfriend, who is a UK citizen, is intending to visit me (in the US) for roughly a month in December under the visa waiver program. He wants to come back to visit me during the summer because he's going to be on break from school, but I was wondering if the visa waiver period will be reset by then. I.e., if he was here for 30 days in December, would he only be able to come for 60 days in starting in June? Or would he be able to stay the full 90 days?